# WebAPI : Return Generic object on the same route : is it RESTFUL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, rest, asp.net-web-api

Here is the technical context: WebApi .NET Core 2.2 and Angular

Here is the business context : on the angular application, admin users can open a specific process : for example, "change address", or "change bank account". all this action create a "process" ( like a workflow ).

when a user will process the request via a task management, he will have different screens with different data to fill in and he can save data partially or completely.

on the api, i would like to have a single route to get the data "in progress" on the process :

```
api/process/{id}/data
```

for exemple, if the process is "ChangeAddress", i will return ChangeAddressDataModel
and if the process is "ChangeBankAccount" i will return ChangeBankAccountDataModel

```
[HttpGet("process/{id}/data")]
public IActionResult GetProcessData()
{
    if(condition)
    {
        return Ok(changeBankAccountModel);
    }

    else if(conditon)
    {
        return Ok(changeAddressModel);
    }
}
```

Angular dev, can get the type of the process and cast model.

**My question is** : Is it REST? Can we do that in good conventions?

if not, should i create a route for each type of process ? like :

```
[HttpGet("process/{id}/change-address-data")] // return NoContent or NotFound if its a ChangeBankAccount process or something else
[HttpGet("process/{id}/change-bank-account-data")]
```

Info : we will have 20+ process type.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You must convert the output to the object you want to return

```
[HttpGet("process/{id}/data")]
public IActionResult GetProcessData()
{
    if(condition)
    {
         //youe operations...
    }
    else if(conditon)
    {
        //youe operations...
    }
    
    return Ok<ClassName>(result);
}
```

In asp.net mvc you have to set this file

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
  {
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "DefaultApi",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
   );
  }
}
```

and In the file Global.asax.cs :

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```

Check this link at the end: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: No, he must not. This is enforced neither by REST nor by OpenApi

Comment: When you said "he must not" what do you mean? Thank you